# How to import other js files in casperjs

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs, file-import

Basically,I have extracted the re-usable functions into a file 'utility.js'.I want to import this file into every CasperJS test script.I'm following the documentation [here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html)

When i try to get it to work,I'm getting the following error.

> 'undefined' is not a function

Folder structure is like this

```
utility.js
test1.js
test2.js
```

Test file has following code as suggested by the above documentation

```
var require = patchRequire(require);
var helper = require('utility');
```

and I access the function in utility.js as follows
    helper.fn_do_something()

I tried to use other methods provided by casperJS,like

```
casper.options.clientscript = [relativepath];
```

But that didn't help.I'm getting the same error.

I'm using PhantomJS 1.9.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use phantom objects within your casperjs script.

Try specifying utility as a library path:

```
phantom.libraryPath=[relativePath]
```

See phantom js docs for further options: http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/property/library-path.html

According to the author of casperjs

> The phantom object is available anywhere within a casperjs env, mostly
>   because a casperjs environment is at first a phantomjs environment.
>   https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/355